# Migrate existing database fields.E340 error on run

Tags: mysql, django, pythonanywhere

Hey everyone I'm fairly new to Python Anywhere, I'm running a django app on python 3.7, I've manually added the tables and fields I need via SSH in MySQL Workbench and ran [migrate.py inpectdb > /app/models.py] then makemigrations then when I run Migrate I get this:

```
ERRORS: auth.Group.permissions: (fields.E340) The field's intermediary table 'auth_group_permissions' clashes with the table name of 'app.AuthGroupPermissions'. auth.User.groups: (fields.E340) The field's intermediary table 'auth_user_groups' clashes with the table name of 'app.AuthUserGroups'. auth.User.user_permissions: (fields.E340) The field's intermediary table 'auth_user_user_permissions' clashes with the table name of 'app.AuthUserUserPermissions'.
```

If I remove the auth tables from the models.py and try to migrate I get:

```
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 276, in query _mysql.connection.query(self, query) django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1071, 'Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes')
```

From what I've read it is conflicting with the settings.py [INSTALLED_APPS] but I'm not sure where to go from here to get the migration to work properly.

Comment: Why did you "manually add the tables and fields I need via SSH in MySQL Workbench"? That is what migrations are for. What made you think you needed to do this?

Comment: Cool story bro. Thanks for the status report.

Comment: The database is a legacy database, from an old system. with quite a bit of pre filled data that I needed to access, this was just the easiest way from the guide I read.

Comment: Just a note regarding a discussion on the same topic here: https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/14430/

Answer (score 0):

The extra tables that you noticed were created by Django because you have the app that creates those tables enabled in your INSTALLED_APPS. From the table names involved, I'm guessing it's django.contrib.auth that's adding them. There are probably other tables that are being created that way, but they are just not clashing with the tables you've already created.

The second error you're getting is because you have tried to create a key on a column (or columns) that is too big to be a key. That may still be as a result of the auth_ tables clashing. For instance, the Django model may be specifying a key on the id of a table, expecting it to be an integer column, but your database has a large string column for id instead.

I suspect that you may continue to have issues as long as you try to get the Django database and your database to be in the same database. Django does, however, support [multiple databases](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/multi-db/) so you could put your legacy database in one database and have your Django database in another. That way, they have no way on stepping on each other.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation Glenn, I was able to keep the models I wanted to use and move to another DB and migrate them over without any problems now that I know what happened. I appreciate the detail this really helps!